# How to remove items out 2d array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array in jquery and would like to remove items from it based on an ID or Value field.

```
 var AccountName = [
            {id: 0,value: "LUCKY'S WINDSCREENS"},
            {id: 1,value: "PALM MOTORS"},
            {id: 2,value: "REFLEX PANELBEATERS & SPRAYPAI"},
            {id: 3,value: "SADAF INVESTMENT T/A YUSUF MOH"}
    ];
```

How do i remove the id and  value out this array?

```
var id = $('#txtAccountID').val();

for (var i = 0; i < AccountName.length; i++)
{
   if (AccountName[i] != "id") { 
   AccountName.splice(i, 1);
   //break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** (Polyfill needed for old browser.)

```
AccountName = AccountName.filter(function(e) {
  return e.id !== 0;
});
```

[**The demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/F9a2T/)

Answer (score 0):

i guess that you want to remove the object from array if its id or value matches the value of `$('#txtAccountID').val()`,

```
var id = $('#txtAccountID').val();
for (var i = 0; i < AccountName.length; i++){
   for(var key in AccountName[i]){
       if(key ==id || AccountName[i][key]== id){
            AccountName.splice(i,1);
       }
   }
}
```

See js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/K5xfv/1/)

If you want to keep only tha matched element then

```
var id = 0;
var temp = null;
for (var i = 0; i < AccountName.length; i++){
   for(var key in AccountName[i]){
       if(  key ==id || AccountName[i][key] == id ){
            temp = AccountName[i];
       }
   }
}
AccountName = temp;
```

Find demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/K5xfv/2/)

Comment: The bottom one creates an object of the id and value, but i need it in the array format like the one posted in my question as i use this a source for a auto complete. Sometimes there would be more then one result needed to be returned where the format would need to look like [{ , },{ , }];